# Error calling another class?

Tags: c#, unity

I get the following error every time I run the code: `` error: error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected ``

```
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
  Stick ();
}
```

Can someone offer a solution?

Comment: In addition to being a question about debugging your code (which is generally off-topic here, this is also a general programming question which is more suitable for SO.

Comment: Apart from that, remember that we are not wizards and without context we are unable to pinpoint what is the exact cause of that error, There are a myriad of reasons why a piece of code might fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it says that `Stick` is actually a type (a class for example), but you treating it as if it was a method. What is `Stick` and what did you intend to do with it?

UPD: As far as I understand, you're trying to make a MonoBehaviour to stick to whatever it touches using a method. It seems like there is already a class called `Stick` which interferes with your code. Calling `this.Stick ()` might solve the issue.

Comment: It did not solve the issue. I get error CS1061.

Comment: Again: what is 'Stick' and what are you trying to do with it?